# Node Express sends a sliced response in Azure App Service

Tags: node.js, azure, express, azure-web-app-service

I have an express application running inside Azure App Service. I came across this weird behavior where I see in the logs that a response of 39.1 MB is sent from the server. But the client only gets a chunk of the response.

As an example, if the server responds with the following,

```json
[
  {
    id: 1,
    name: 'john doe',
    address: 'park street'
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: 'john simon',
    address: 'ranger avenue'
  },
]
```

On the client side, I'm receiving the following,

```json
[
  {
    id: 1,
    name: 'john doe',
    address: 'park street'
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: 'john simon',
```

As you can see, the response is sliced in the middle and it does not include the following.

```json
    address: 'ranger avenue'
  },
]
```

When I used cURL command to get the response I can see that it is waiting until my response is fully completed but it never does and I see this in the terminal.

```sh
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
 30 39.1M   30 12.0M    0     0  46706      0  0:14:39  0:04:29  0:10:10     0
curl: (56) LibreSSL SSL_read: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL, errno 54
```

I am guessing in between the client and my express server, Azure App Service is meddling with my response data which I could not able to figure out.

Here is my `web.config` file.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <webSocket enabled="false" />
    <handlers>
      <add name="iisnode" path="server.js" verb="*" modules="iisnode"/>
    </handlers>
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="NodeInspector" patternSyntax="ECMAScript" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="^server.js\/debug[\/]?" />
        </rule>

        <rule name="StaticContent">
          <action type="Rewrite" url="public{PATH_INFO}"/>
        </rule>

        <rule name="DynamicContent">
          <conditions>
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="True"/>
          </conditions>
          <action type="Rewrite" url="server.js"/>
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
    
    <security>
      <requestFiltering>
        <hiddenSegments>
          <remove segment="bin"/>
        </hiddenSegments>
      </requestFiltering>
    </security>

    <httpErrors existingResponse="PassThrough" />
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Any help is much appreciated. Thank you!

**Edit:**

This behavior is random and sometimes I get the full response in the client-side. And I noticed this usually happens for large responses. If it is let's say 1 MB, it won't happen (at least when I was testing).

Comment: Try to modify the interface and write the returned data into fixed format data, as you provided above, try again to see if the problem recurs.

Comment: Sorry, I did not understand what you meant by the interface?

Comment: How do you get the returned data from the webapp? There should be an api interface. I suggest you write the data as a fixed string and access it directly.

Comment: From the webapp, I am sending the response using `res.json(data)` and `res` is an Express Response object. Just for testing purposes, I used both Postman and cURL as my clients to retrieve the data. I still do not understand what do you mean by `write the data as a fixed string` since I am writing the data only once.

Comment: `res.json([{id: 1,name: 'john doe', address: 'park street'  },{id: 2,name: 'john simon',address:'ranger avenue'}]);`

Comment: I guess you made an error when getting the json data. So let you write a static string for testing.

Comment: @JasonPan Actually, I should have mentioned that this is random and sometimes I get the full response. And I am sure that the response data is written as a whole. Basically, I can see in the log that 39.1 MB response was returned from the server. The problem is on the client's end I am receiving only a chuck of what was returned.

Comment: If it appears randomly, it is recommended to add log to print the log, you can check it yourself, and then raise a support ticket for help.

Comment: Is there any progress? If you find an answer, I suggest you post your answer and share it with other forum users.

Comment: Thank you for the follow-up. I did not find the root cause or an answer to this question particularly. However, I was able to solve the issue by making my result a readable stream and piping it directly to the response. The solution is described in this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63555610/response-streaming-in-express-does-not-work-in-azure-app-service